# Suppose f is defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose f is defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. If $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x<1$, then $f(1)\ge0$? This statement seems correct to me but is there any way to prove it?

Comment: Use Heine's definition of continuity.

Answer (score 2):

Start with $f(1)=\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$, that follows from continuity of $f$. Suppose $f(1)<0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $0<|x-1|<\delta$, $|f(x)-f(1)|<-f(1)/2$ (take $\varepsilon=-f(1)/2$ in the definition of limit).

Can you derive a contradiction, now?